# Faithful semi-finite normal weights

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The above screenshot is from Takesaki's book(Vol 2, Chapter VIII)
I wonder how to prove the implication (ii)→(i)?

By Theorem 2.11, we have $\sigma_t^{\psi}(x)=h^{-it}\sigma_t^{\varphi}(x)h^{it}$ for all $x\in M$. We have $\psi\circ\sigma_t^{\psi}(x)=\psi\circ\sigma_t^{\varphi}(h^{it}xh^{-it})$.

How to show that $\psi\circ\sigma_t^{\varphi}(x)=\psi(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modular group is defined via the GNS representation for $\psi$. So
\begin{align}
\psi(\sigma^\psi_t(x))&=\langle \sigma_t^\psi(x)\Omega,\Omega\rangle
=\langle \Delta^{-it} x\Delta^{it}\Omega,\Omega\rangle
=\langle x\,\Delta^{it}\Omega,\Delta^{it}\Omega\rangle=\langle x\,\Omega,\Omega\rangle=\psi(x). 
\end{align}
The equality $\Delta^{it}\Omega=\Omega$ follows from $\Delta\Omega=\Omega$, and this in turn follows by definition:
$$
\Delta\Omega=FS\,\Omega=F\Omega=\Omega. 
$$

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. We need to prove $\psi\circ\sigma_t^{\varphi}(x)=\psi(x)$.

Comment: $\sigma_t^{\varphi}(x)=h^{it}\sigma_t^{\psi}(x)h^{-it}$, $\psi\circ\sigma_t^{\varphi}(x)=\psi(h^{it}\sigma_t^{\psi}(x)h^{-it})$, I cannot see why it is equal to $\psi(x)$.

Comment: Pro Argerami, accordingvto your proof, I attemped to prove the above conclusion in the following way :                        
  \begin{align}
\psi(\sigma^\varphi_t(x))&=\langle \sigma_t^\varphi(x)\Omega,\Omega\rangle
=\langle h^{it} \sigma_t^\varphi(x) h^{-it}\Omega,\Omega\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: I cannot check that $\psi\circ\sigma_t^{\varphi}(x)=\psi(x)$ and how to prove $\Delta^{it}\Omega=\Omega$ according to $\Delta\Omega=\Omega$?