# GNS constructions of two faithful positive linear functional

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are two faithful positive linear functionals on a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$. Then $\rho_i(x)=\langle x\omega_i,\omega_i \rangle$,
where $\omega_i=1+N_{\rho_i}$,
$N_{\rho_i}=\{x\in A: \rho_i(x^*x)=0\}(i=1, 2).$

Since each $\rho_i$ is faithful, we have $N_{\rho_i}=0$. Then each cycic vector $\omega_i=1(i=1, 2),$ $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ have the same GNS construction.

Does the above conclusion correct?

Answer (score 2):

Martin's example says it all but here is another, more pedestrian counter-example.

Let $A=C([0, 1])$ and let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be  two disjoint, dense subsets of $[0, 1]$.  For example,  take
$$
  D_1=\mathbb Q\cap [0, 1],  \quad  \text{and} \quad   D_2=(\mathbb Q+\pi )\cap [0, 1].
  $$

Fix an enumaration $\{d_n^i\}_{n\in {\bf N}}$ for each $D_i$, and define a state $\rho _i$ on
$C([0, 1])$ by
$$
  \rho _i(f) = \sum_{n\in {\bf N}} 2^{-n}f(d^i_n), \quad\forall f\in C([0, 1]).
  $$

It is not hard to  see that the GNS representation $\pi _i$ associated to $\rho _i$ is equivalent to the representation of
$C([0, 1])$ on $\ell ^2$, where each $f$ in $C([0, 1])$ is mapped to the diagonal operator with diagonal entries
$f(d^i_n)$.

This implies that $\pi _i$ is faithful,  so one might wonder whether or not  $\pi _1$ and $\pi _2$ are equivalent.    To see that
they are not,  it is enough to observe that,  for any  given $f$, the point spectrum (eigenvalues) of the operator
$\pi _i(f)$ is
$$
  \sigma _p(\pi _i(f))= \{f(d^i_n): n\in {\bf N}\},
  $$
and if $f$ is any injective function,  this imlies that
$$
  \sigma _p(\pi _1(f))\neq   \sigma _p(\pi _2(f)).
  $$

This shows that the operators $\pi _1(f)$ and $\pi _2(f)$ are not conjugate to each other,  and hence $\pi _1$ cannot be equivalent to $\pi _2$.

Comment: But both of the cyclic vectors are 1 according to the GNS construction. Where is the wrong place,  we cannot view $x$ as $\pi_{\rho_i}(x)$?

Comment: The inner product makes a big difference!

Comment: We can define $\pi_{\rho_i}(a):A/N_{\rho_i}\rightarrow A/N_{\rho_i}$ as following : $\pi_{\rho_i}(a)(x+N_{\rho_i})=ax+N_{\rho_i}$, put $\omega_i=1+N_{\rho_i}$, then $\omega_i$ is a cyclic vector for $\pi_{\rho_i}$ and $\rho_i(x)=\langle 
 \pi_{\rho_i} (x)\omega_i,\omega_i \rangle$, we view $\pi_{\rho_i} (x) $ as $x$, since $\pi_{\rho_i}$ is faithful and for $x,y \in A$, we can define $\langle x+N_{\rho_i}, y+N_{\rho_i} \rangle=\rho_i(y^*x)$(i=1, 2). I cannot find the difference.

Comment: Given a point $a$ in $D_1\setminus D_2$, consider a sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ of continuous functions converging pointwise to
the characteristic function $1_a$, e.g. $f_n(x) = e^{-n(x-a)^2}$.  Then, relative to the inner product given by $\rho _1$,
one has that $f_n+N_{\rho_1}$ converges to a (non-zero) eigenvector of $\pi _1(f)$ with eigenvalue $f(a)$. But $f_n+N_{\rho_2}$ converges to zero
relative to the inner product given by $\rho _2$.

Comment: I wonder whether the inner product defined as above is correct. If it is correct, where is the wrong point? Is the completion of $A/N_{\rho_1}$ different from the completion of  $A/N_{\rho_2}$ ?

Comment: The inner product you defined is correct.  Like all separable, infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces, the completion of
$A/N_{\rho _1}$ is isomorphic to the completion of $A/N_{\rho _2}$, but only under some non-cannonical isomorphism.  In particular,
noting that in our case $N_{\rho _1}=N_{\rho _2}=\{0\}$, the function
  $$
  f+N_{\rho _1} \to  f+N_{\rho _2}
  $$
  is **not** continuous, and hence does not extend to the completions.  This is why I said above that the inner products makes a big difference!

Comment: Thanks. I have sawn a conclusion :  every faithful normal state $\omega$ on a VNA $M$ has the following form: $\omega(x)=\langle x\Omega, \Omega\rangle$. I wonder whether the cyclic vectors for different normal faithful states are the same? We can take $\Omega=1$?

Answer (score 1):

No, even if $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are states. For instance take $A=\text{UHF}(2^\infty)$ and take $\rho_1$ to be the trace and $\rho_2$ to be the Powers' state $\phi_\lambda$. Then $\pi(A)''$ is the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor, while $\rho_2(A)$ is a type III$_\lambda$ factor.

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: I have sawn a conclusion : every faithful normal state $\omega$ on a VNA $M$ has the following form: $\omega(x)=\langle x\Omega, \Omega\rangle$.    I wonder whether the cyclic vectors for different normal faithful states are the same? We can take $\Omega=1$?

Comment: I cannot  prove the conclusion in this link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4030517/faithful-semi-finite-normal-weights/4030798#4030798